# Image resize is not working on a smaller value

Tags: magento-1.9, php, image, phtml

So I am in checkout/cart/minicart/default1.phtml. I am trying to change the image size on my minicart from 180 to 60.  When I do this magento just breaks and stops loading resources after that line. This is my default line.

```
<div class="product-image">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(180); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" >
 </div>
```

This is what I have tried.

```
<div class="product-image">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(60); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" >
 </div>
<div class="product-image">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(60,60); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" >
 </div>
```